# unable to display console in the apps

Tags: configuration, console

I have created a console app. I have assigned it to a profile (X). I have designed the layout and tested the console layout and I am happy with the way it is laid out. Now when I log in as a user with profile (X) the console is not available from the app drop down list. Have I missed something in the setup to ensure that they can see the console form the app menu.

Comment: have you checked the Service cloud user checkbox on the user detail?

Comment: That did it, thanks, do you want to put it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the service cloud user check box on the user detail will do the job.